# Can I have multiple instances of a RequireJS Module?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

I am obviously missing some concept/understanding and most definitely javascript OO basics!

I am loving using RequireJS, and my web app now looks more like a structured app now rather than a whole heap of crazy code.

I am just struggling to understand how/if the following is possible.

I have a module which acts as a base dataservice module called **dataservice_base** as follows:

```
define(['dataservices/dataservice'], function (dataservice) {

    // Private:     Route URL
    this.route = '/api/route-not-set/';
    var setRoute = function (setRoute) {
        this.route = setRoute;
        return;
    }

    //  Private:    Return route with/without id 
    var routeUrl = function (route, id) {
        console.log('** Setting route to: ' + route);
        return route + (id || "")
    }

    //  Private:    Returns all entities for given route
    getAllEntities = function (callbacks) {
        return dataservice.ajaxRequest('get', routeUrl())
        .done(callbacks.success)
        .fail(callbacks.error)
    };

    getEntitiesById = function (id, callbacks) {
        return dataservice.ajaxRequest('get', routeUrl(this.route, id))
        .done(callbacks.success)
        .fail(callbacks.error)
    };

    putEntity = function (id, data, callbacks) {
        return dataservice.ajaxRequest('put', routeUrl(this.route, id), data)
        .done(callbacks.success)
        .fail(callbacks.error)
    };

    postEntity = function (data, callbacks) {
        return dataservice.ajaxRequest('post', routeUrl(this.route), data)
        .done(callbacks.success)
        .fail(callbacks.error)
    };

    deleteEntity = function (id, data, callbacks) {
        return dataservice.ajaxRequest('delete', routeUrl(this.route, id), data)
        .done(callbacks.success)
        .fail(callbacks.error)
    };

    //  Public:     Return public interface
    return {
        setRoute: setRoute,
        getAllEntities: getAllEntities,
        getEntitiesById: getEntitiesById,
        putEntity: putEntity,
        postEntity: postEntity,
        deleteEntity: deleteEntity
    };

});
```

As you can see, I am referencing dataservices/dataservice, which is actually the core AJAX call mechanism (not shown, but really just basic jQuery ajax call in a wrapper).

What I am trying to do is allow this base dataservice module to be "instanced" as follows (within another module - snippet code only):

```
define(['dataservices/dataservice_base', 'dataservices/dataservice_base', 'dataservices/dataservice_base'], function (dataservice_profile, dataservice_qualifications, dataservice_subjects) {

    //  Set the service route(s)
    dataservice_profile.setRoute('/api/profile/');
    dataservice_qualifications.setRoute('/api/qualification/');
    dataservice_subjects.setRoute('/api/subject/');
```

As you can see, I am trying to include the same **dataservice_base**(defined above) 3 times, but in the function references, I am trying to refer to each instance by named vars i.e:

dataservice_profile, dataservice_qualifications, dataservice_subjects

.. and of course I am trying be able to set a unique **setRoute** value for each of those instances to use further on in the module.. whilst leveraging the common calls (get,puts,posts etc).

Obviously I am missing a few things here.. but any help to point me back on the road would be very gratefully received!!

Kind Regards,
David.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need to include your dependency only once and use the [new](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3658673/1916258) keyword. Possibly you will need to refactor so that the common functions are in a depending module:

```
define(['dataservices/dataservice'], function (dataservice) {
    var dataservice_profile = new dataservice();
    var dataservice_qualifications = new dataservice();
    var dataservice_subjects = new dataservice();

    //  Set the service route(s)
    dataservice_profile.setRoute('/api/profile/');
    dataservice_qualifications.setRoute('/api/qualification/');
    dataservice_subjects.setRoute('/api/subject/');

    // define needs to return something
    return {
       profile: dataservice_profile,
       qualifications: dataservice_qualifications,
       subjects: dataservice_subjects
    };
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, brain-freeze or whatever.. problems of working alone sometimes!

So, as @asgoth mentioned, quite rightly had to clear my mind and think things through a bit!

I ended up with a re-factored dataservice_base module as follows:

```
define(['dataservices/dataservice'], function (dataservice) {

    //  Set any class/static vars

    //  Set the instance function
    function dataservice_base(setRoute) {

        var self = this;

        self.route = setRoute;
        console.log('setting route: ' + self.route);

        function routeUrl(route, id) {
            console.log('** Setting route to: ' + route);
            return route + (id || "")
        }

        self.getAllEntities = function (callbacks) {
            return dataservice.ajaxRequest('get', routeUrl())
            .done(callbacks.success)
            .fail(callbacks.error)
        }

        self.getEntitiesById = function (id, callbacks) {
            return dataservice.ajaxRequest('get', routeUrl(self.route, id))
            .done(callbacks.success)
            .fail(callbacks.error)
        }

        self.putEntity = function (id, data, callbacks) {
            return dataservice.ajaxRequest('put', routeUrl(self.route, id), data)
            .done(callbacks.success)
            .fail(callbacks.error)
        }

        self.postEntity = function (data, callbacks) {
            return dataservice.ajaxRequest('post', routeUrl(self.route), data)
            .done(callbacks.success)
            .fail(callbacks.error)
        }

        self.deleteEntity = function (id, data, callbacks) {
            return dataservice.ajaxRequest('delete', routeUrl(self.route, id), data)
            .done(callbacks.success)
            .fail(callbacks.error)
        }

    } // eof instance

    return dataservice_base;
}
```

and of course again as @asgoth mentioned, I only need to of course include one reference to the dataservice_base module, and instance it for my needs as follows:

```
define(['dataservices/dataservice_base','viewmodels/viewmodel_profile', 'viewmodels/viewmodel_qualifications', 'viewmodels/viewmodel_subjects', 'app/common'], function (dataservice_base, viewmodel_profile, viewmodel_qualifications, viewmodel_subjects, common) {

    var dataservice_profile = new dataservice_base('/api/profile/');
    var dataservice_qualifications = new dataservice_base('/api/qualification/');
    var dataservice_subjects = new dataservice_base('/api/subject/');

    // do whatever now with those instance objects...
}
```

SO.. now all working!

I guess the only other thing I need to do is looking up about cleaning up process to ensure these objects are released.. however there will only ever be a few.. but still..

thanks again @asgoth

Comment: I was struggling with this concept. This answer makes it very clear! ... I suppose the key here is to understand that RequireJS always returns the same instance of a module, no matter how many times you "require" it. If your module returns a constructor function instead of a static object, however, you can create instances from the constructor function using the new keyword in the client module. The same constructor function is returned by RequireJS everytime, but that's what we want because it's a template, a class. It's the job of the client module to create instances from that class.

Comment: """ I suppose the key here is to understand that RequireJS always returns the same instance of a module, no matter how many times you "require" it. """

Almost. It does cache the first required instance, but ONLY if it's the same exact module on the same exact path. 

This means that if you have the same lib "xxx" in 2 different paths (for different parts your app), like: app/modules/foo/xxx and app/modules/bar/xxx, then requiring each while bring a different instance. This can happen e.g. if you have a different package.json for each module, and they ask for the same library.

Comment: +1 I have been looking all over the web for an example which showcases how DI can work with require.js in (somewhat) the same way DI works in C# when using StructureMap, AutoFac etc Until I came across your post I just couldn't figure out how to inject "Singletons" vS "Transient" vS "AlwaysUnique" instances of dependencies

Answer (score 2):

Just return a function instead of a object like this

```
return function(){
    return {
        // your public interface goes here
    };
}
```

Now you can create new instances of your plugin with `new componentName()`.